# How to stop java producer from updating schema registry?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I have a java producer which produces to a kafka topic. I use schema registry to make sure the messages which are produced to the topic are valid. But when I produce an invalid message, the topic schema updates in accordance to the invalid message rather than not accepting the invalid message.
I have come across parameters like auto.register.schemas and use.latest.version but they're producer configs, and anyone can produce without those configs and alter the schema which defeats the purpose of schema registry.

How do I enforce schema registry to all topics who produce to it?

Answer (score 0):

Fahad , **auto.register.schemas=false** will prevent schemas from being registered. Can you try this option and see how it goes

```
Properties kafkaProps = new Properties();
kafkaProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "<broker-address>");
kafkaProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, x.class);
kafkaProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, y.class);
kafkaProps.put("schema.registry.url", "<schema-registry>");
kafkaProps.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS, false);
```

Comment: This isn't what was being asked. What if `y.class` is StringSerializer? Then data is still produced to the topic without the registry, and it breaks consumers that need schemas.

Answer (score 0):

> when I produce an invalid message, the topic schema updates in accordance to the invalid message

Did you disable the default backwards compatibility on the Registry?

Otherwise, is your schema backwards compatible? What exactly are you changing? If you change the serializer setting, then the Registry is not used anymore.

> anyone can produce without those configs and alter the schema

Indeed.

> defeats the purpose of schema registry

Enforcement is not its purpose. Its purpose is more of a database of schemas... Anyone can also insert random data into a database without *authorization controls*.

> enforce schema registry to all topics who produce to it?

You can't (for free, or from the Registry itself). That is currently a (paid) feature of [Confluent Server](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/schema-validation.html#change-the-subject-naming-strategy-for-a-topic) only.

Without this, you could, instead, setup Security settings on the Registry to prevent "anyone" from registering a schema, and similarly on Kafka to prevent "anyone" from producing to certain topics. This way, only *authorized users* will "*shoot themselves in the foot*".